# Question about reputation computation

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I can't understand how this situation could arise:

http://aoeu.se/so/rep235.png

I'm usually able to reach 245 in reputation when I have 3 accepted answers.

Comment: You're only asking this because you wanted to brag.

Comment: Hahah... naah then I would have folded yesterdays entries and included a few more lines ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple possible options I can think of. All of them are generally solved by recalculating your reputation at `/reputation`, which probably says 245 for today already.

- One of your first 20 upvotes was retracted, and you haven't gotten an upvote since then to counteract it, rendering you at 235 until you recalc or get upvoted.
- One of your upvoted posts got deleted early in the day, you recalced your reputation since then and thus have temporarily set today's reputation cap to 190. It'll recover at your next recalc.
- Someone who voted on your posts has been merged with another user that voted on the same post, or otherwise eliminated from the picture. You'll be stuck at 190 for the day's max reputation cap until you recalc.

Comment: Wow, interesting explanations. And you're right, `/reputation` does indeed report +245.