# Why am I sometimes not able to get full 200 rep (not counting accepts)?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Most of the time when I exceed my 200 cap, I get 200 + the sum of all accepted answers. I am curious why sometimes that is not the case. Today I had 2 accepted answers, meaning the most I could come away with was 230. Yet I seem to have been capped at 220:

[image]

Now I'm being totally honest here, I really don't care about the 10 rep points. I'm just curious if there are non-obvious factors that go into the math that calculates the cap. I did down-vote a couple of poor questions today, but I did not down-vote any answers.

Comment: It gets noddy when somebody removes a vote.  Only a recalc can whack it back into shape, visit the /reputation page and scroll all the way down to click "Trigger Reputation Recalc".

Comment: Damn, that corrected today's but it removed 70 or 80 rep points from some previous date. Should have kept my mouth shut. :-)

Comment: @Aaron - I do a recalc once a week or so to keep myself in line.  I get a lot back from downvotes on deletes/closes too so sometimes it nets out (if you are mean enough)

Comment: The rep system has bugs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103903/bug-in-reputation-tab

Comment: You'll also get less than expected if you get a downvote as your last vote of the day, as there is no later upvote to cancel it out. I've had days where I ended up with like 228 from ~25 upvotes, one downvote, and two accepts.

Comment: See also [Question about reputation computation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93569) (one possible duplicate)

Comment: Probably for the same reason as [Whats up with my rep today? I started off this morning with negative reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100299/whats-up-with-my-rep-today-i-started-off-this-morning-with-negative-reputation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone has removed a vote from one of your old answers, or a question has been deleted/migrated along with your answer which had 1 upvote, or you have deleted an answer with 1 upvote yourself. Reputation score is held in different sources and not every action which affects reputation takes all those sources into account. This is "by design".

Pushing the recalc button at buttom of https://stackoverflow.com/reputation will align everything.